# Add thousand separator in Woocommerce email 'Quantity' values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is a very challenging thing I came across. I know the code should be:

```
$quantity = number_format($quantity, 0, '.', ',');
```

I have looked everywhere in the Woocommerce plugin and docs and around the internet but where to insert this code? In which hook or template file? Please help me put a thousand separator for the 'Quantity' row in the order emails template, as shown in the attached screenshot.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```php
function format_quantity( $quantity ) {
    return number_format($quantity, 0, '.', ',');
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', 'format_quantity', 1);
```

Comment: thank you soo much man. How did I miss that even after looking through 'email-order-items.php'? This is great. :D Could you please give me tips on how to find the needed hooks for any issue? Maybe my approach is flawed.

Comment: Just keep searching, I'm sure next time you will get it :)